# How to fit 2 div's content in bootstrap 4 when the site is shrunk / in mobile mode?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am building a new responsive website and I have some div sections in it. One of my sections has content which is a slider with its text description, unfortunately, these two things have a lot of space between them when the site is shrunk. How can I make the slider and it's text description closer when the site is shrunk?

Running Bootstrap 4.3.1 and JQuery 3.4.1. In the past, I've tried to change the CSS 'padding:-100px;' to make their space closer than before but still remain a lot of space, when I change again to 'padding:-120px;' space doesn't change at all. i think it min-padding is only at "-100px".

index.html

```
<div id="course" class="offset">

  <div class="col-12 narrow text-center"><!-- to make space (margin) between the top and the neath and then text and button we use col-12, narrow to make the column (single column) narrow, -->
    <h1>Rental Bachtiar Medan Hehe</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="course-class">
          <iframe marginheight="1" marginwidth="1" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" src="sliderCarousel.html" seamless></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="course-class">
          <h3>Text Description</h3>
          <p>Animate.css and Waypoints.js allow for smooth animations scrolling down the site.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

style.css

```
/*---------- COURSE SECTION ------------*/
#course .narrow{
  width: 90%;/*75%*/
  margin: 1.5rem auto -70px;/*1.5rem auto 0*/
  padding-top: .2rem;
}

.course-class h3{
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0;/*.4rem*/
  text-align: left;
}

.course-class p{
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  text-align: left;
}

/*---------------------- iframe Section-----------------------------*/
iframe[seamless] {
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;/*auto*/
  margin-bottom: 0px;/*new added*/
}

/*---------------------- Media Queries --------------------------*/
/*-- Additional CSS For Mobile Interface --*/
@media(max-width: 767px){
  .narrow h1{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  /* Setting Padding space between iframe to text*/
  .col-md-6 .course-class h3{
    padding-top: -100px;
  }
  .col-md-6 .course-class iframe[seamless] {
    padding-bottom: -100px; 
  }
  /* End Setting Padding space*/

  }
}
```

I expect the output of index.html at course section will show the 'iframe' and ('h3', 'p') with space only "5px" when the site is shrunk / in mobile mode.

Comment: There is no negative padding in CSS

Comment: change the height of the `iframe` !

Comment: @Chrollo Lucifer Use `xs` and `sm` for mobile interface. ex : `<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">`

Comment: @Krish but the content shifted when i use negative. but the min-value is -100px. when i add more value the content didn't shift.

Comment: @ChrolloLucifer simulate your issue in a fiddle or codepen. so we can have a proper understanding.

Comment: @adel yes it works when i shrink the window the space become closer. but unfortunately my slider is snipped a little bit when i maximize the window / desktop mode. Is there another way to make the content space closer without snip the slider size when in desktop mode?

Comment: @ChrolloLucifer  on your `@media(max-width:767px)` add `iframe{height:auto}` and leave it `300px` for bigger screen size

Comment: @adel i have tried what you suggest, but now the slider is sitill snipped a little bit when the window is shrink. So i put the "height" size to "250px;" in order to match with my "h3" text. i think my size would be a problem if the user turn his phone in landscape.

Comment: @Krish : i haven't familiar yet to those stuff kris i am sorry. actually my point is to adjust the "margin" or space between my "iframe" slider and my "h3" text when the window is shrunk.

Comment: @ChrolloLucifer the problem is from your slider! please post a codepen so i can help you better. i have this codepen for you and its working : https://codepen.io/iziz96/pen/NWKNJOo

Comment: @adel i am not sure adel, i think the slider is responsively fit to the "iframe" area. because the padding is changing when i set the value of "iframe" height.
By the way can we use more than a hmtl file in codepen?

Comment: @ChrolloLucifer can you post a picture  width inspect for the issue!

Comment: @adel https://bachtiarlubis.smugmug.com/Stackoverflow/i-FGQKBh3/A this is my picture that i am using.

Comment: @ChrolloLucife i meant a picture of your website showing the problem !

Comment: @adel i am sorry there it is https://bachtiarlubis.smugmug.com/Stackoverflow/i-H5VcVb9/A. it looks like the problem is solved, but i am worry when the users turn their phone into landscape the slider hight will not be responsive.